# SimpleDateFormat vs LocalDateTime - Parsing Differences with postfixes

Tags: java, date, java-time

I'm trying to move some processing from `SimpleDateFormat` to the new `java.time` packages.

In the following example:

```
final String str = "28/11/2016 11:58:51 AM UTC (date)";
final String format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss a z";
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(format).parseObject(str));
System.out.println(LocalDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(format)));
```

`SimpleDateFormat` parses the String, but `LocalDateTime` throws a `DateTimeParseException`.

The part in brackets is variable, so `SimpleDateFormat`'s approach works well. Is there a way of making `LocalDateTime` have this behaviour?

Comment: On my machine, `SimpleDateFormat` cannot parse the string either... Why don't you just extract the relevant part from the string before parsing it?

Comment: You can try using DateTimeFormatterBuilder class of java.time.format package for this, it provides a lot of flexibility in defining the patterns. DateTimeFormatter formatter = new DateTimeFormatterBuilder().appendPattern(format)
  .appendLiteral(" (date)").toFormatter();

Comment: @Sweeper Isn’t that a locale problem? As I think you know, `AM` is English and cannot be parsed in a locale with a different language.

Comment: @PallaviSonal If the postfix is always ` (date)`, parsing it as literal text is a good idea, also for validation. You don't need a builder for that. We can just enclosexthe literal text in single quotes in the format pattern string.